# Why does my router have an HTTP server on port 5555?

Tags: router, port, http

I just did a port scan using nmap on my router (a Netgear WNDR3700) from the LAN side and found these ports to be open:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
23/tcp   open  telnet
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
3333/tcp open  dec-notes
5555/tcp open  freeciv
```

I tried connecting to the telnet but that went nowhere. To me, ports 53, 80, 139, and 445 seem like they're supposed to be there and I don't know how to poke at them. I looked for ports 3333 and 5555 online and found [this closed ask](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72308/what-is-my-router-listening-for-on-ports-5555-and-3333) where the poster said that he got a HTTP response from port 5555. Although he never got an answer, I immediately checked this on my router and found that it was the same, returning:

```
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not found
< Connection: close
< Content-type: text/html
< 
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Found</H1>The requested URL was not found on this server.</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the netgenie app uses port 5555 to talk to and setup the Netgear modem.  [This](https://github.com/MatMaul/pynetgear/issues/6) is the article I found.  In it they talk about netgenie making soap calls to the device on port 5555. Which I understand is sort of of a superset or uses http.
The 3333 port , looking at that link I'd guess it's part of the netgenie discovery , but I could not find any support for that

To poke on DNS port 53, run nslookup and use the command "server IPaddress".  Then ask it to resolved names to IP addresses.
In any case I think you will find that the dhcp server is setting the DNS server to the router, and that will,be using port 53 so it's being poked all the time,
Port 80 is http so just point Firefox to you modems address , you will get you modems config screen.  So you know that works.

So those extra ports are, I think, to support the smart config tools. I generally download dd-wrt to my modems, sothey are removed. But I don't think they are a problem as I would think they are only usable inside the LAN

Comment: They can do an internet side port scan to verify your last statement.....https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2